# ASP.NET MVC3 Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, roles, action-filter

I'm currently creating an application using the MVC3 framework. I understand how to use roles with filters like:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

My question is:

**Where do I set roles? Is it on login? How is this achieved?**

Comment: What Membership Provider are you using? Are you using one of the built in providers or are you just using a forms authentication ticket?

Comment: I'm using the forms authentication ticket, the application has been built from the ground up so I wasn't aware of Membership Providers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating a Forms Authentication ticket on your own you would generally use the UserData portion of your ticket to store information related to your user. This could be the roles.

Then in the Global.asax on the Application_AuthenticateRequest event you would parse your Forms Ticket and assign the roles to the current security principal.

Here are some guides on Forms Auth with different providers:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx

In general I usualy write my own System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal and System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity  to do all the work for me.

```
public class UserIdentity: System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity 
{
    public string[] Roles { get; private set; }
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string UserName { get; private set; }
    public int UserID { get; private set; }

    public UserIdentity(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket) : base(ticket)
    {
        if (ticket.UserData != null && ticket.UserData.IndexOf("|") != -1)
        {
            string[] dataSections = ticket.UserData.Split('|');

            //Get the first name
            FirstName = dataSections.Length >= 3 ? dataSections[2] : "";

            //Get the username
            UserName = ticket.Name;

            #region Parse the UserID
            int userID = 0;
            int.TryParse(dataSections[0], out userID);
            this.UserID = userID;
            #endregion

            this.Roles = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(dataSections[1], ",");

        }
    }
}

public class UserPrincipal : System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal
{
    public UserPrincipal(UserIdentity identity) : base(identity, identity.Roles )
    {
    }
}
```

And in your Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity)
        {

            HttpContext.Current.User = new CAA.Utility.Security.UserPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is CAA.Utility.Security.UserIdentity?  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as CAA.Utility.Security.UserIdentity : new Utility.Security.UserIdentity(((System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Ticket));                


        }
    }
```

And to write the ticket:

```
                System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.Username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), false, String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", user.UserID ,user.Roles.ToString(), user.FirstName ), System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));

                if (model.RememberMe)
                     cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;


                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

The code might be hard to follow but the logic is that the custom "UserPrincipal" will auto-parse the UserData section of the Forms Auth ticket for what ever information you want to store there. In my case I'm storing name, roles, id, etc. In my code the namespace "CAA.Utility.Security" is where my custom Identity and Principal are stored.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

> Where do I set roles?

That will depend on what role provider you are using in web.config. If you are using the default `AspNetSqlRoleProvider` provider:

```
<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

then you set roles in your `aspnet_Roles` table. You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs). But if you are using a custom roles provider then it will depend how is this provider implemented.